# image inserted in directory folder not in database?

Tags: php

image inserted in directory folder not in database? please see the code, the image can be viewed   in the folder but not in database the pc.gif is inserted instead on the command else the filename is     executed on the command but the else is executed? the first command is proper why the second command   is executed instead.

```
    if($action=="insertproject"){

    if ($_FILES['logo']['name'] != "") { 

    $imageInfo = getimagesize($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name']); // get image size
    $width = $imageInfo[0]; // image width
    $height = $imageInfo[1];  // image height

    if($height > 2000 || $width > 2000){
        echo "<script> alert('Image is to big! Try to resize the picture!') </script>";
        exit;
    } // check size 

    $newimg1 = date("YmdHis").".jpg";  // set name for new image
    $newimg2 = date("YmdHis").".pdf"; // set name for pdf if is necesary

    if(stristr($_SERVER['OS'],"win")){
        $path = "prodimg/";
    } // determin path of image folder
    elseif(stristr($_SERVER['OS'],"linux")){
        $path = str_replace("admin.php","",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . "prodimg/";
    } 
    else {
        $path = "prodimg/";
    }

    move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], $path . $newimg1  );
    }  // copy image in image folder

    else{
    $newimg1="pc.gif"; 
    } // if is not posible than set image name as pc.gif

    $serviceid = $_POST['serviceid'];
    $projectcode = $_POST['projectcode'];
    $projecttitle = $_POST['projecttitle'];
    $update =  $_POST['update'];
    $projectstatus = $_POST['projectstatus'];
    $progress = "on progress";
    $sector = $_POST['sector'];

    $dateofrtecreview = $_POST['dateofrtecreview'];
    $dateapprovedatrpmolevel = $_POST['dateapprovedatrpmolevel'];
    $dateendorsedtonpmo = $_POST['dateendorsedtonpmo'];
    $dateapprovednpmo = $_POST['dateapprovednpmo'];
    $datereceivedbyrpmo = $_POST['datereceivedbyrpmo'];
    $expectedoutput = $_POST['expectedoutput'];
    $yearassistancereceived = $_POST['yearassistancereceived'];
    $setupinvestment = $_POST['setupinvestment'];
    $beneficiaryinvestment = $_POST['beneficiaryinvestment'];
    $projectdescription = $_POST['projectdescription'];

    $res = mysql_query("insert into     appointment_detail(`serviceid`,`picture`,`projectdescription`,`dateofrtecreview`,`dateapprovedatrpmol evel`,`dateendorsedtonpmo`,`dateapprovednpmo`,`datereceivedbyrpmo`,`expectedoutput`,`projectcode`,`projecttitle`,`update`,`status`,`projectstatus`,`sector`,`setupinvestment`,`beneficiaryinvestment`) 
      values('$serviceid','$newimg1','$projectdescription','$dateofrtecreview','$dateapprovedatrpmolevel',' $dateendorsedtonpmo','$dateapprovednpmo','$datereceivedbyrpmo','$expectedoutput','$projectcode','$pro jecttitle','$update','$progress','$projectstatus','$sector','$setupinvestment','$beneficiaryinvestmen t')");

   echo "<script>location.replace('admin.php?action=showallprojects')</script>";
   }
```

Comment: Going with the obvious answer here... `$_FILES['logo']['name'] == ""`

Comment: `'$beneficiaryinvestmen t')")` you got space in there it should be`'$beneficiaryinvestment')")`

Comment: @Bryan what do you mean ??

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 fixed it still not working

Comment: see the answer posted by mee

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I mean if the filename is pc.gif(which question states it is) the else is executed. The file is probably already on the server before he tried to upload.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I think you found another problem, but not the one he is asking about

Comment: @bryan thanks for the response his logic is also wrong. but he is not replying any more so i dont know he bothered any more or not,

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like this Read the comment in the code, and use mysqli or PDO

```
$res = mysql_query("insert into     appointment_detail
        (`serviceid`,`picture`,`projectdescription`,`dateofrtecreview`,`dateapprovedatrpmolevel`,
        `dateendorsedtonpmo`,`dateapprovednpmo`,`datereceivedbyrpmo`,`expectedoutput`,
        `projectcode`,`projecttitle`,`update`,`status`,`projectstatus`,`sector`,`setupinvestment`,
        `beneficiaryinvestment`) 
      values('$serviceid','$newimg1','$projectdescription','$dateofrtecreview',
            '$dateapprovedatrpmolevel',' $dateendorsedtonpmo','$dateapprovednpmo',
             '$datereceivedbyrpmo','$expectedoutput','$projectcode',
            '$projecttitle','$update','$progress','$projectstatus','$sector',
            '$setupinvestment','$beneficiaryinvestment')");
```

**These were your mistake**

/

```
'$beneficiaryinvestmen t this should be $'$beneficiaryinvestment

    //$pro jecttitle' this should be this $projecttitle'
    //dateapprovedatrpmol evel this should be this dateapprovedatrpmolevel
```